# Haskell - Produce a List of People from a list of lists

Tags: haskell

The List of Lists contains the following entries.

```
[
  ["John","Doe","38\r"],
  ["Jane","Doe","35\r"]
]
```

The Person data type is constructed as follows:

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String
                     , lastName :: String   
                     , age :: Int  
                     } deriving (Show)
```

I am trying to make a list of Persons in Haskell such that the final Person list will look as follows:

```
[
Person {firstName = "John", lastName = "Doe", age = 38},
Person {firstName = "Jane", lastName = "Doe", age = 35}
]
```

Any help is appreciated! Please and thank you!

Comment: Hint: first make a function that takes a single list like `["Jane","Doe","35\r"]` and turns that into a `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

So we need a function of this type:

```
f :: [[String]] -> [Person]
```

And there's a function which can help us - `map`

```
stringsToPerson :: [String] -> Person
f = map stringsToPerson
```

Now, a fundamental problem becomes clear(er) - `stringsToPerson` is not type-safe. A user could give it an empty list and the function has no choice but to return an error. Better types would be:

```
stringsToPerson :: (String, String, Int) -> Person
stringsToPerson :: [String] -> Maybe Person
```

Buuut assuming you want to stick with the type you chose, you can do it with pattern matching:

```
stringsToPerson [firstName, lastName, age] = Person firstName lastName (read age)
```

Comment: Since `Student` takes precisely an Int, Haskell will infer the type of `read` automatically, and so you don't need to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

Your may do as follows;

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String
                     , lastName :: String
                     , age :: Int
                     } deriving (Show)


mapper :: [[String]] -> [Person]
mapper = map makePerson
         where makePerson [f,l,a] = Person f l $ read a

*Main> mapper [["John","Doe","38\r"], ["Jane","Doe","35\r"]]
[Person {firstName = "John", lastName = "Doe", age = 38},Person {firstName = "Jane", lastName = "Doe", age = 35}]
```